# Countdown timer , auction bid in last 10 min

Tags: php, wordpress, timer

I am currently working on an auction page, but I have encountered a small problem or it is just a blockage in my head.

Managed to put , when the bid is pressed , it extend the auction timer by 10 min. But i have to put that only the last 10 minutes of the auction produces for 10 minutes when you click on the bid now, not the whole time the auction is running. I hope I didn’t complicate things.

```php
$expiry_date = get_post_meta($_POST['pid'],'listing_expiry_date',true);
            
$expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $expiry_date . " +300 seconds") );  
        
update_post_meta($_POST['pid'],'listing_expiry_date', $expiry_date );
```

Comment: (1) 10 minutes=600 seconds (**not** 300 seconds) . (2) Do the update only when (now + 10 minutes) > expiry date, so add this condition please